# Get File Location Using Combo box c#

Tags: c#, filewriter

I have a combo box to select a drive. then I want to write a file to that selected location by using C# File Create(String, Int32, FileOptions, FileSecurity)

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        string path = @"E:\My WORK\text.txt";
        for (int i = 1;i> 100; i++) {

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create(path);

            }
            else { 

            }
        }

    }
```

I want to get input using a combo box and create this file in that location.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, what's not working and we can help. Also what's the question?

Comment: So what's stopping you from doing what you want?